# How to use Prism MVVM in WinUI 3 Desktop

Tags: mvvm, prism, winui

I am new to WinUI 3 and PRISM Library.

Do we have PRISM Library support in WinUI 3? If the answer is Yes, which is the the library?

After doing initial search...

I saw Prism.Uno is supporting WinUI 3. Is my understanding correct?

To try a sample, I have done below steps and created a WinUI 3 project:

1. Visual Studio 2019 Professional with all required components for WinUI3
2. Windows App SDK From Visual Studio, click on menu Extensions > Manage Extensions
3. After installing, create a new project by selecting "Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)" template.
4. Prism.Uno 8.1.97 From Visual Studio, click on menu Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console and type command "Install-Package Prism.Uno -Version 8.1.97"

Now after building the solution I am getting below error:

> Error CS0433 The type 'DefaultOverloadAttribute' exists in both 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET, Version=10.0.19041.21, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Uno.Foundation, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

How to resolve this error? Is this the right library I am referring?

[image]

Comment: I am looking to do the same, and replicated your error. Have you opened an issue at the project site? https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues

Comment: I have added it in the Public discussion. Please find the below link:
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/discussions/2630

Thank you.

Comment: Do I need to add it in the Issues section also?

Comment: Reported as issue in GitHub
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2632

Jerry, Thank you for the suggestion to add as an issue.