# Can I use Prism for WinUI 3 apps?

Tags: prism, winui-3

I'd like to use Prism in a WinUI 3 app, and I saw the Prism v8.1 release.

> Additionally Prism 8.1 offers a new Prism.Uno.WInUI platform target for those wishing to build either native WinUI3, or Cross Platform WinUI 3 apps with Uno Platform.

I'm confused about Uno. I'm **not** using Uno, can I still use Prism in a WinUI 3 app without using Uno?

If yes, which packages do I need to install and in which projects? (I'd like to use DryIoc)

I guess Prism.DryIoc.Uno.WinUI must be added to the WinUI 3 app project.

But what about the other packages for using Prism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a question about an error while using Prism.Uno with WinUI 3: [How to use Prism MVVM in WinUI 3 Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216637/how-to-use-prism-mvvm-in-winui-3-desktop)

In the comments section, there is a link to a GitHub discussion that is held in Prism GitHub repository. Here is the link: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2632

In this discussion, on Dec 7, 2021, it is stated that there is not any support for WinUI 3 other than Prism.Uno.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to use 'Dryloc', you could try to use one of these Nuget packages:

- Prism.Container.Extensions
- Prism.DryIoc.Extensions

They should both be of general use and not target a specific UI technology.

If you install 'Prism.DryIoc.Extensions' using the Nuget-Package manager, dependent packages should be installed automatically.

See [Github - Prism.Container.Extensions](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Container.Extensions)

Note there is also a package '**Prism.Core**' that does not target a specific UI framework either. If contains features like an event aggregator.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I asked. Maybe I was not clear, I asked how to use Prism in a WinUI3 app

Comment: You wrote "I'd like to use DryIoc", that is why my answer refered to this part.

Comment: Thanks again, but using DryIoc is really not the main point of the question.

Comment: I did a small edit, I hope it's more clear? Many thanks again